# "Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table" in c# application

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, dataset

i have windows application in which i am constructing dataset with two datatables one is "Products" and other is "TaxView".I have included sample code below.in this code i am getting error **`Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table`**

```
 public DataTable[] getProductViewDetails(ArrayList ssd,ArrayList tax)
        {
            DataTable Products = new DataTable();
            DataColumn SalesDetailID = Products.Columns.Add("SalesDetailID", typeof(System.INT32));
            DataColumn BrandName = Products.Columns.Add("BrandName", typeof(System.String));
            DataColumn ProductName = Products.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(System.String));
            DataColumn Quantity = Products.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(System.INT32));
            DataColumn Rate = Products.Columns.Add("Rate", typeof(System.INT32));
            DataColumn Per = Products.Columns.Add("Per", typeof(System.String));
            DataColumn Discount = Products.Columns.Add("Discount", typeof(System.String));


            DataTable TaxView = new DataTable();
            DataColumn SalesTaxDetailID = Products.Columns.Add("SalesTaxDetailID", typeof(System.Int32));
            DataColumn TaxAmt = Products.Columns.Add("TaxAmt", typeof(System.Int32));
            DataColumn Total = Products.Columns.Add("Total", typeof(System.Int32));
            DataColumn TaxDesc = Products.Columns.Add("TaxDesc", typeof(System.String));
            DataColumn TaxValues = Products.Columns.Add("TaxValues", typeof(System.INT32));

            foreach (SalesStructDetails s in ssd)
            {
                //int previoustaxdetail;

                Products.Rows.Add(1,HP, Printer, 2, 2100, pcs, 125);

                foreach (TaxDetail t in tax)
                {                                       
                    if (s.SalesDetailId == t.SalesDetailID)
                    {
                        TaxView.Rows.Add(1, 125, 75, VAT, 4);

                    }
                }
            }

            DataTable[] dt = new DataTable[2] { Products, TaxView };
            return dt;
        }
```

i am getting error at the line **`TaxView.Rows.Add(1, 125, 75, VAT, 4);`**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look carefully - you are adding the tax column definitions to the products table. Add them to the tax table instead. Example:

```
DataTable TaxView = new DataTable();
DataColumn SalesTaxDetailID = Products.Columns.Add(blah);
```

Should be;

```
DataTable TaxView = new DataTable();
DataColumn SalesTaxDetailID = TaxView.Columns.Add(blah);
```

Also: consider using regular classes rather than DataTable

Comment: Sorry i didn't notice.Thanks for help